# PHP: Populating an array with form values

Tags: php, arrays, forms, for-loop, populate

I have a questionnaire form with 5 questions, each having 5 radio button options. Now, I want to capture this form data upon pressing of a Submit button. I am getting stuck at populating an array with values of these radio buttons sent through a POST method.

The code that I have written is throwing the error: **"Notice: Undefined index: 'radio11' in E:\xampp\htdocs\dataCollect\form1.php on line 11"**

The code is enclosed below:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnForm1'])){
for($count = 1; $count < 6; $count++){
$radioName = "radio1".$count;
$arrForm1 = array($_POST["'".$radioName."'"]);
}}
<?>
<html>
<body>
<form name="ESForm" action="form1.php" method="post">
<table name="ESTable" style="oTab1">
<tr>
    <td style="oRow">1. AAAAAA <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio11" value="1">Never<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio11" value="2">Seldom<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio11" value="3">Sometimes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio11" value="4">Often<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio11" value="5">Always<br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="oRow">2. AAAAAA<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio12" value="1">Never<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio12" value="2">Seldom<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio12" value="3">Sometimes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio12" value="4">Often<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio12" value="5">Always<br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="oRow">3. AAAAA <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio13" value="1">Never<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio13" value="2">Seldom<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio13" value="3">Sometimes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio13" value="4">Often<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio13" value="5">Always<br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="oRow">4. AAAaA <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio14" value="1">Never<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio14" value="2">Seldom<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio14" value="3">Sometimes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio14" value="4">Often<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio14" value="5">Always<br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="oRow">5. AAAAA <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio15" value="1">Never<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio15" value="2">Seldom<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio15" value="3">Sometimes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio15" value="4">Often<br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio15" value="5">Always<br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="btnForm1" value="Submit"></td>       
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If no value is selected for the radio button the key is not sent. So you will need an `isset($_POST["radio11"])` (or similar) for each value.

Comment: Dear Halcyon, should I not be relying on using POST for Submit button? Because I want PHP to pick up values after the button is pressed.

Comment: `$_POST` is fine, the alternative would be `$_GET` which has the same 'problem'.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
$arrForm1 = array($_POST["'".$radioName."'"]);
                         ^^^^----------^^^^----useless
```

The `"'"` quotes are absolutely unecessary.  This is all that you should have:

```
$arrForm1 = array($_POST[$radioName]);
```

And why wrap the radio button's value in an array. You'll only ever get back one value from each radio button set anyways.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. The reason I intend to warp values into the array as subsequent sections which have many more questions. Want to capture these values into an array and submit them into the database at the end of the questionnaire. Do you think this approach is inefficient?

Comment: you're creating a new single-item array on each iteration, so it's still pointless work. if you want to build an array of the values, then it'd have to be `$arrForm1[] = $_POST[$radioName]`

Comment: I got your point on this Marc. Pardon me for my ignorance as I am absolutely new to PHP, but how do I capture the value from each of the 5 group of radio buttons in PHP? I tried the basic approach of simply assigning it to variable but it doesnt even recognize the radio button names. It seems that PHP can pick up values of only one set of radio buttons. See the code below:                                                                                            if(isset($_POST[$btnName])){
$valRdo1 = stripslashes($_POST['r11']);
  }

Comment: why test for the existence of `$btnName`, but then hard-code `r11` inside the if?